# Is there any cost key for creating new archetypes?

Tags: genesys

When I read over the archetypes and races examples in the *Genesys Core Rulebook* I noticed that I was NOT able to find any calculation key for how many XP are left for a character hailing from this archetype. In the end I used a key myself that looked a bit similar.....per + in an attribute that has no corresponding - in another one I reduced 10 XP from a total of 110. And for each special ability aside from teh basic + in 2 skills also results in 10 XP less.

Still though even with that I did not come close to some of the races. So I guess that there was no dedicated cost key that was being used in the examples.

Thus the question here: IS there any cost key?

Comment: Have you read the "Create a Species or Archetype" section on page 192? The writers explain the pricing of stats and abilities there. They take into account stuff like synergy - if a skill point has synergy with another ability it would actually cost more XP to add it to an archetype\species. Seems to me this kind of thing heavily relies on common sense, even by the official guidelines.

Comment: @Ekadanta could till be that htey internaly went with some sort of key for their examples,... though I fear not (as some remaiing xp to be spent jsust make no sense if sort of a key would have been used)

Answer (score 2):

The "Creating a Species or Archetype" section on page 192 of the *Genesys Core Rulebook* provides costings, but explicitly calls out that

> [...] These aren’t rules, but rather guidelines that will help you create a species that people are going to want to use, but won’t break your game.

The third-party *[Archetypal Species](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/290044/Archetypal-Species)* document by Christopher Ruthenbeck provides expanded material in a similar vein.